# reordering python bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a CSV file of 'nobelprize' information. I'm trying to draw a bar plot that shows the first 10 cities according to alphabetical order on the x axis.
So far I can just show the first 10 cities but not alphabetically

```
df['Birth City'].value_counts()[:10].plot(kind='bar', color='grey')
plt.xlabel("Birth Cities by alphabetical order", labelpad=14)
plt.ylabel("Total Number of Laureates per city", labelpad=14)
plt.title("Most prolific cities.", y=1.02)
```

Comment: [Using this  ?](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html#pandas-series-sort-values)

Comment: Not sure how I order just the Birth City column though, there are about 12 different columns so line 1 accesses the column i'm interested in

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this issue by breaking down the problem.

1. We can first create a pandas series with the values you want.

   ```py
   df_birth_city = df['Birth City'].value_counts()[:10]
   ```
2. Once we have the series we can now sort it by alphabetical order by sorting the index.

   ```py
   df_birth_city = df_birth_city.sort_index()
   ```
3. Now that your values are sorted you can plot them.

   ```py
   df_birth_city.plot(kind='bar', color='grey')
   plt.xlabel("Birth Cities by alphabetical order", labelpad=14)
   plt.ylabel("Total Number of Laureates per city", labelpad=14)
   plt.title("Most prolific cities.", y=1.02)
   ```